# How to code login (passport) authentication for two different users types? Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I am new to Node.js.

For my application, I have two different type of users being doctors and patient. Currently, I been coding for the login and registration for patients and it works. I starting to code the login for the doctors and it doesn't seem to be working. Below is the passport.js. I watched a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FOq4cUdH8k&ab_channel=TraversyMedia) to learn how to code the login and registration.

I think the issue is within the passport.js, I'm not really sure how to code it, when it comes to the second user.

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const Patient = require('../models/patients');

module.exports = function(passport) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
      Patient.findOne({
        email: email
      }).then(patient => {
        if (!patient) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'That email is not registered' });
        }

        bcrypt.compare(password, patient.password, (err, isMatch) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, patient);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Password is incorrect' });
          }
        });
      });
    })
  );

  passport.serializeUser(function(patient, done) {
    done(null, patient.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    Patient.findById(id, function(err, patient) {
      done(err, patient);
    });
  });
  
const Doctor = require('../models/doctors');

module.exports = function(passport) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (demail, dpassword, done) => {
      Doctor.findOne({
        demail: demail
      }).then(doctor => {
        if (!doctor) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'That email is not registered' });
        }

        bcrypt.compare(dpassword, doctor.dpassword, (err, isMatch) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, doctor);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Password is incorrect' });
          }
        });
      });
    })
  );

  passport.serializeUser(function(doctor, done) {
    done(null, doctor.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    Doctor.findById(id, function(err, doctor) {
      done(err, doctor);
    });
  });
  
}}:
```

This is my doctor.js in route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');

const Doctor = require('../models/doctors');

router.get('/doctorregister', (req, res) => res.render('Doctorregister'));

router.get('/doctorlogin', (req, res) => res.render('Doctorlogin'));

module.exports = router;


router.post('/doctorregister', (req, res) => {
    const { dname, dqualification, dlocation, dpractice, demail, dmobileno, dpassword, dpassword2 } = req.body;
    let errors = [];
  
    if (!dname|| !dqualification || !dlocation || !dpractice || !demail || !dmobileno  || !dpassword || !dpassword2) {
      errors.push({ msg: 'Please enter all fields' });
    }
  
    if (dpassword != dpassword2) {
      errors.push({ msg: 'Passwords do not match' });
    }
  
    if (dpassword.length < 6) {
      errors.push({ msg: 'Password must be at least 6 characters' });
    }
  
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      res.render('doctorregister', {
        errors,
        dname, 
        dqualification, 
        dlocation, 
        dpractice,
        demail, 
        dmobileno, 
        dpassword, 
        dpassword2
      });
    } else {
        Doctor.findOne({ demail: demail }).then(doctor => {
        if (doctor) {
          errors.push({ msg: 'Email already exists' });
          res.render('register', {
            errors,
            dname, 
            dqualification, 
            dlocation, 
            dpractice,
            demail, 
            dmobileno, 
            dpassword, 
            dpassword2
          });
        } else {
          const newDoctor = new Doctor({
            dname, 
            dqualification, 
            dlocation, 
            dpractice,
            demail, 
            dmobileno, 
            dpassword,
          });
  
         //hashing password in the database
         bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(newDoctor.dpassword, salt, (err, hash) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              newDoctor.dpassword = hash;
              newDoctor.save()
                .then(doctor => {
                  req.flash('success_msg', 'You are now registered and can log in')  
                  res.redirect('/doctors/doctorlogin');
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            });
          });
        }
      });
    }
});
 
router.post('/doctorlogin', (req,res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/doctordashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/doctors/doctorlogin',
    failureFlash: true
  })(req, res, next);
});

router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  req.flash('You are logged out');
  res.redirect('/doctors/doctorlogin');
});
```

Comment: You only need one logic to login both. Why are you creating two separate passport logic?

Comment: You should have just 1 UserSchema and then in there u can have a property like `type:Patient` or `type:Doctor` as @AvivLo said u only need 1 login logic

Comment: ah okays, it because I had made two schemas, one for the doctor and one for the patient, in the models. Hence why I tried making two separate passport logic. If I was to make it just one userSchema, how would differentiate the two, since doctors require different info for registering compared to a patient. I'm so sorry if the question seems really dumb, I'm really new to node.js.@ShivamSood

Answer (score 0):

The two different type of users should be different through the user Schema if you are using mongoose and mongoDB as Travesty-Media uses in some of his videos, and through the permissions in different sections of your web app.

Use the same passport code that you have used for the patient user and it works. Passport takes the user info and turns it into a Bearer auth token and sends it to the client, and then when it receives it from the client it decodes it to see what kind of user is logging in...

Different users have different info but same Passport logic, even if there are 2 different patient-users. So the logic from patient to doctor regarding the Passport is the same.

If you want the patient to have access to different routes of your app, you need to insert a middleware to that route to check if the type of user is the same with what you want it to be, but after passport has got the info from the token it has received from the client side.

Comment: I like traversy media so much :D